# Example for BitBucket Java API

Tags: java, bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I'm looking for some example code for BitBucket Java API. 
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/reference/java-api/

My requirement is to commit a file into a BitBucket cloud repo.

Please help.

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Comment: Can you provide more information? There should be tons of tutorials about using `git` in Java, like JGit - where exactly are you struggling with your code?

Comment: BitBucket has the library "https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/reference/java-api/" to perform all the operations. I want to use that library, but couldn't find any example to start.

Comment: That library is for Bitbucket Server, not Bitbucket Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I am wrong, but my guess is that you think you could use this Java API to easily communicate with the Rest API in your own Java project.

But that it is not. The documentation is about the classes which can be used inside Bitbucket Server Plugins, so being in the same Java Runtime Environment.

But googling for "Bitbucket Cloud Rest Client Java" was giving me already several interesting results. So, maybe just give them a try then.